# Will Arduino Mega support stepper motor NEMA 24, NEMA 34

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper

Will two stepper motor NEMA 24, 10 kg cm, 2. 8 amp, 24 vdc work at same time on Arduino Mega and when they stop stepper motor NEMA 34, 34 kg cm, 4amp, 24 VDC will work or not? This is my first project please help me to choose the controller.

Comment: Properly running multiple stepper motors is a bit challenging if they need to move at the same time, but any Arduino-based 3d printer firmware manages to do so.  If only one needs to move at time then it is far simpler.  Selecting the power drivers for a given motor is not an Arduino question and therefore not on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 4x Nema 24s for a CNC project of mine.  They only need a couple of signals/pins each from the Arduino to work, the rest is up to the stepper controller board.

For my steppers, I'm using TB6600s, since I need ~3.5 amps per motor/channel.  There are others out there that'll work, but it's what I saw other people at my maker space using.

Nema34s would probably need higher rated amps, so that would determine what controller you need to use.

In fact, every motor is rated for different amps and voltages, so that will always determine what motor controller you use.  Since you need a higher voltage to run the motor controllers than the Arduino, using a separate stepping power supply is a requirement.

The Arduino gets hooked to the step/pulse and direction pins of the motor controller and the other pins on the motor controller go elsewhere.  The CNC motor controller shields you normally see are for lower amp controllers and do most of the pin connections for you.  With the higher amperage motors, you'll have to do this yourself.

When you determine what motor controller you are going to use, find a wiring diagram for it (and maybe a friend) to figure out how it should be wired.